# Yii2 hasMany with many conditions in join statement

Tags: join, conditional-statements, yii2

I need to define more conditions in the JOIN statement.
How can I make this in Yii2 with a hasMany relation?:

... LEFT JOIN orders ON (customer.id = order.customer_id AND orders.position = 1) ...

I have a DataProvider for GridView. It look like this:

```
...
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Customer::find()
        ->joinWith('orders');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
...
```

Model:

```
...
public function getFirstOrder()
{
    $query = $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id']);
    return $query;
}
...
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: you can write mysql query in create command

Comment: I'm pretty sure at this point in time there isn't a way because of [a bug in Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6792).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function search($params){


    $activeDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                                        "query" => Customer::find()
                                                   ->joinWith('orders')
                              ]);

    // Valdate the search $params.

    // Build your query depending on search params. I am assuming we get key => value pair in params

     foreach($params as $key => $value){

      $activeDataProvider->query->andWhere("`$key`  = '$value'");           

     }

     return $activeDataProvider;

}
```

I hope that helps you :)

You can also preview the generated sql using:

```
    $command = $activeDataProvider->query->createCommand();
    print_r ($command->sql);
```